# How to access json objects in views/lib in couchdb design document

Tags: couchdb

I've read lots of places that I can use require("views/lib/modulename") to access a script shared between views in my design document. Can I do the same with a json object?

I understand that the scope is different in views but I would think that if scripts are accessible then data would be too.

I guess I can do this in erica with macros and in kanso through some kind of preprocessors but isn't there a native way?

```
"views": {
    "lib": {
        "module: "function(){...}",
        "data": {}
    },
    "view": {
        "map": "function (doc) {
            var module =  require('views/lib/module');
            var data = ??
        }"
    }
}
```

Comment: could you just put the data you want in a function inside of a shared script?

Comment: @WiredPrairie If I have to, I will do that, but I'd prefer not to